# how to make a json function work with a jinja2 template

Tags: python, json, jinja2

I have a json handler in my main.py file and I am attempting to have this handler communicate with jinja2 template. The handler is as follows:

```
class JSONHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        content = get_content(True)
        self.response.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
        tshirt_json = []
        for t in content:
            tshirt_json.append({"id": t.unq_id, "product_name": t.product_name, "price": t.price, "qty": t.qty})
        self.write(json.dumps(tshirt_json))
```

My template for simplicity sake will be briefly listed as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><center><h1>Gigi's Catering Menu</h1></center></div>
<form method = "post">
{% for i in range(150) %}
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Large Gourmet Meat & Cheese Tray</th>
    <th colspan="2"><p>Fresh Roast Sirloin Beef, Baked Ham, and Roasted Turkey with Swiss and American Cheese<br><i>Serves 20-25 people</i></p>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Selection</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Price would be $54.99 Per Tray</td>
    <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="{{1}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Large Gourmet Meat & Cheese Tray">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{54.99}}">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}"><div class="error">{{ error }}</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
```

Here is the tail end of that jinja2 template:

```
    <td>Brownie</td>
    <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="140">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Dessert - Brownie">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}"><div class="error">{{ error }}</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cookie</td>
    <input type="hidden" name="unq_id" value="141">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="Lunch Box: Dessert - Cookie">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="True"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="qty" id="q01" value="{{qty}}"><div class="error">{{ error }}</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<hr style="height:0px">
<br>
        <label>
        <div>Additional Comments and/or Special Requests</div>
        <textarea name="body">{{body}}</textarea>
        </label>
    <div class="error">{{ error }}</div>
    <input type="button" value="submit">
    <input type="reset">
</form>
     {% if chkbox is True %}
          {% tmp_order = (i.unq_id, i.product_name, i.price, i.qty) %}
     {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that the user will make a selection on the template and click on the submit button. Of which their selections will compiled into a dictionary using aforementioned json function and be able to do my validations against that function. I will greatly appreciate the community's help considering I am working with stuff that I am still struggling. I am thanking the community in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with that data. Why do you want it to be JSON? What sort of validation are you doing, and why wouldn't you use some kind of forms framework?

Comment: I am using a form in my framework I am unable to just collect what the user is selecting and being able to process that information. Furthermore, later on in the form is what I call a lunchbox selection area where they pick out their meat, bread, cheese, desserts etc. which validation will be needed on that part but collecting that information is crucial.